# TYPO3 6.2 extbase pageType in Template

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid, extbase

I want to use an action from a Controller as an Ajax Request with pageType, but I want also use the same action on pages as content elements. Why i should create two actions?

But now I don't know how I can use an `<f:link.action>` with the actual pageType? I can set the Option pageType `<f:link.action pageType="12345">` manually. But this should do automaticly like

```
<f:link.action pageType="{pageType}">
```

Do you have an idea, how i can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Rhetoric question: Automatically basing on... what ?*

Standard page num in TYPO3 is 0 and it's also by default used in all linking ViewHelpers, if you want to use something else you need to write it exactly in the view (*`pageType="12345"`*) or, for an instance configure it in your *setup.txt* file in your extension:

```
plugin.tx_yourextension.settings.ajaxPageType = 12345
```

So you can use it in your view like:

```
<f:link.action pageType="{settings.ajaxPageType}">
```

Disadvantage of this approach is that you need to repeat this pageNum in settings and also in plugin's bootstrap, anyway that's better then checking everytime which number exactly is this.

TIP: Don't forget to flush system cache to take *setup.txt* changes into account.

**P.S.**

Of course I assume that you're bootstrapping your ajax actions like ie:

```
yourAjaxAction = PAGE
yourAjaxAction {

  typeNum = 12345
  10 = USER
  10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = YourExtension
    pluginName = YourFePluginRegisteredProperly
    vendorName = VENDOR_NAME
  }

  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
    no_cache = 1
  }
}
```

If you do - you don't need to use `f:link.action` VH, if you don't... you should start :)

Comment: basing on from where it called. If I have the action as content Element, all links in it should render with pageType = 0. If it called from ajax, all Links should have the pageType = 12345

Comment: But this, don't solve the Problem. The links in the Template are rendered still without a pageType